# What's the explanation for the distribution of this kind of dice roll?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, dice

Consider the following type of dice roll for the attack damage in some tabletop RPG:

- Roll three six-sided dice.
- Pick two of them that have a sum greater six.
- The remaining die is the attack damage.
- If no combination of two dice has a sum greater than six then the attack damage is zero.

Naturally players want to maximize damage and thus pick the lowest possible sum of two dice that is still greater than six.

I tried to simulate that roll to see the probability distribution of the attack damage and was surprised that there is a probability of ~20% to roll the maximum damage of six.

Here is the full distribution after 1M rolls:

| dmg | p |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.195335 |
| 1 | 0.153332 |
| 2 | 0.097448 |
| 3 | 0.125001 |
| 4 | 0.101249 |
| 5 | 0.115615 |
| 6 | 0.21202 |

I makes sense to me that the attack damage is biased towards higher values, because players will choose the higher one when having the choice, but I kind of expected the distribution to increase from 1 to 6 as a result of that instead of fluctuating so much.

So what's happening here?

---

Inspired by some of the comments I plotted the distribution with this roll/selection for different kind of dice:

[image]

The target value is always the most probable value when rolling two dice and taking the sum (so 7 for d6, 11 for d10 and 21 for d20).

Comment: There are only $6^3=216$ possible outcomes...you can get the exact answers easily enough (at least with mechanical assistance).

Comment: As @lulu states, there are $216$ possible outcomes, and the tallies from $0$ through $6$ are $[42, 33, 21, 27, 22, 25, 46]$. If you divide those by $216$, you'll get more or less the proportions you tabulated. I don't have an intuitive explanation for the fluctuations, though.

Comment: I mean, I have a *general* explanation, or a guess at one, in that we progress through cases where (a) there is no pair of dice that sum to $7$ or more; (b) we have to add the largest two results to get to $7$ or more; (c) we add the minimum and maximum; and (d) we add the smallest two results. Each of those transitions is a discontinuous change in the behavior as the attack damage progresses respectively through (a) no damage; (b) smallest die damage; (c) middle die damage; and (d) largest die damage. So it's not surprising that there are fluctuations, but we still need to tally the cases.

Comment: I suspect there's no analytical way to do that with as small a face count as $6$. I'm curious as to what would happen if we "rolled" three uniformly distributed values from $0$ to $1$, and played the same rules, but with the pair-sum threshold set at $1$. I might try that in a bit.

Comment: This is a trivial note but *really* there are only $\left(\!\binom{6}{3}\!\right) = 56$ possible outcomes (not equally likely, of course) and so doing this by hand is not hard at all.

Comment: @JBL: I agree it's not hard, but it is a little tedious, and probably prone to error. Also, if you reduce to $56$, you also need to track how often each combination (*vice* permutation) shows up—also easy, also tedious, also prone to error. :-) ¶ I also don't think the d$6$ case is very illuminating; that's why I suggested the continuous extension.

Comment: For three uniformly distributed values from $0$ to $1,$ discarding two values that sum to at least $1,$ there is exactly $1/4$ chance of zero damage. But unlike the uniform $[0,1]$ distribution, where any two values have an expected sum of $1,$ two $6$-sided dice have an expected sum greater than $6.$

Comment: @BrianTung: The continuous result is similar to the discrete case with many sides: (a) the probability of $0$ increases with the cuttoff in an intuitively natural way;   (b) there is a counter-intuitive $\omega$ type shape with two low areas (corresponding to the $2$ and $4$ with $6$-sided dice) though with low cuttoffs not all of the left part of this appears; and (c) with cuttoffs more than $1$ some low positive values are equally probable.

Comment: In the continuous version (three numbers chosen uniformly in $[0, 1]$, remove two whose sum is $> 1$), it seems that (aside from the point-mass at $0$) the probability density function is proportional to  the piecewise function $\begin{cases} 3t^2 - 2t + 1/2, & t < 1/2 \\ 3t^2 - 4t + 3/2, & t > 1/2\end{cases}$, with minima at $t = 1/3$ and $t = 2/3$.

Comment: @JBL: I'll check that later against my empirical plot, but that looks approximately right, with a proportionality constant of $3$.

Comment: @JBL: That is consistent with my "$\omega$ type shape" comment. Is that easily extended to other cuttoffs? (I suspect there may be a constant piece with a cuttoff below $1$ and a linear piece with a cuttoff above $1$)

Comment: @Henry I found the constant piece but not the linear piece (instead another quadratic) -- plausible?

Comment: @BrianTung See my answer below.

Comment: @JBL: Well done. I lost patience with the bookkeeping long before I finished. :-)

Comment: @JBL Yes, plausible - the right hand part of your third chart looked linear in simulation but apparently is slightly curved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an answer to the question being discussed in comments by @Brian Tung and @Henry.

Let's start with the closest analogue of the original question: three numbers $a, b, c$ are uniformly generated in $[0, 1]$, and the final score is computed by choosing two of them that add to at least $1$ and discarding them; or is equal to $0$ if no two of them sum to $1$.

As @David K observes in comments, the probability of getting score $0$ is exactly $\frac{1}{4}$: for example, we can see that the situation $a + b + c \leq 1$ forms a tetrahedron of volume $\frac{1}{6}$ in the corner of the probability space $[0, 1]^3$, while the situation $a + b + c > 1$ but $a + b < 1$, $a + c < 1$, $a + c < 1$ forms a tetrahedron with vertices $(0, 0, 1)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(1, 0, 0)$, and $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ which is exactly half as large.  So we have a point-mass of $\frac{1}{4}$ at score $0$.

The rest of the probability distribution will be continuous.  Let's compute the probability that we get final score $t$, contingent on the first die coming up $t$.  (Presumably this is where the factor of $3$ Brian Tung noted comes from, since there are three dice.)  When $0 < t < \frac{1}{2}$, the space of pairs $(b, c)$ that work consists of three triangles in $b, c$-plane: one is defined by the inequalities $b + c \geq 1$, $0 \leq b \leq t$, $1 - t \leq c \leq 1$, the second by the inequalities $b + c \geq 1$, $t \leq b \leq 1- t$, $t \leq c \leq 1 - t$, and the third by the same inequalities the first with $b, c$ switched.  This gives a probability density of $\frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{(1 - 2t)^2}{2} + \frac{t^2}{2}$, which can be written in the form in my comment above.  The situation when $ \frac{1}{2} < t < 1$ is very similar (actually you get the same pictures, just with $t$ and $1 - t$ reversed, so the PDF is symmetric across $t = \frac{1}{2}$).

[[image: Case <span class=]$\alpha = 1$ graph" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0f1N.jpg)

Now let's suppose that instead we have a cutoff of $\alpha$ (i.e., we discard two dice whose sum is at least $\alpha$, instead of whose sum is at least $1$).  Set aside the point-mass at $0$ (which in principle we could compute after the fact).  When $\alpha$ is large ($1 \leq \alpha \leq 2$) we end up with three regimes: for $t < \alpha - 1$, the event that we get score $t$ is the same event that $b + c \geq \alpha$ (since we don't have to worry about discarding $t + b$ or $t + c$ in this case), with constant probability density $\frac{(2 - \alpha)^2}{2}$ (just as @Henry observed).  When $t > \alpha - 1$, the situation is very similar to the case $\alpha = 1$: for $\alpha - 1 < t < \frac{\alpha}{2}$, the probability space in the $b,c$-plane consists of three triangles: one defined by $b + c \geq \alpha$, $\alpha - 1 \leq b \leq t$, $\alpha - t \leq c \leq 1$, a second defined by $b + c \geq 1$, $t \leq b \leq \alpha - t$, $t \leq c \leq \alpha - t$, and the third the same as the first with $b, c$ switched.  This gives density $\frac{(t - (\alpha - 1))^2 + (\alpha - 2t)^2 + (t - (\alpha - 1))^2}{2}$.  The third regime is the mirror image of the second across the line $t = \frac{\alpha}{2}$.

[[image: Case <span class=]$\alpha = 1.5$ graph" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8UGi.jpg)

When $\alpha$ is small ($0 \leq \alpha < 1$) there are again three regimes; omitting the details, if $t < \frac{\alpha}{2}$ then the probability density is (proportional to) $2 \times t \cdot \frac{(1 - \alpha) + (1 - \alpha + t)}{2} + \frac{(\alpha - 2t)^2}{2}$, if $\frac{\alpha}{2} < t < \alpha$ then the density is the mirror-image of the first case (replacing $t$ with $\alpha - t$), and if $t > \alpha$ then the density is $t^2 - \frac{\alpha^2}{2}$.

[[image: Case <span class=]$\alpha = .5$ graph" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rO4G.jpg)

Comment: Using three dice with $n \gg 6$ you get similar shapes for the discrete distribution

Answer (score 3):

For the record, the exact count of ordered rolls with a given "score" is, in order from $0$ to $6$: $$\{42,33,21,27,22,25,46\}$$
which closely matches the simulation.

Perhaps it helps with intuition (or, at least, understanding...it's hard to have useful intuition here, I think) to do the count for score $2$, to see why there are so few cases.  The "problem" is that it's hard to get a $5$ or $6$ in there since $2+5>6$ and the score will probably be the other roll.

Specifically, the possible unordered rolls with score $2$ are:

$$\{2,2,6\},\{2,2,5\},\{2,4,4\},\{2,1,6\}, \{2,3,4\}$$

There are $3$ orderings for each of the first three, and $6$ for each of the last two, to get the total of $21$.

For a score of $1$, by contrast. we have:
$$\{1,1,6\},\{1,4,4\},\{1,5,5\},\{1,2,5\}, \{1,3,4\},\{1,3,5\}, \{1,4,5\}$$

And for a score of $3$ we get:
$$\{3,3,4\},\{3,3,5\},\{3,3,6\},\{3,1,6\}, \{3,2,5\},\{3,2,6\}$$

As I say, it's hard to have intuition...the selection process is a bit more subtle than it appears at first.

Comment: I do not have a problem with one of the values being less common than the others, but it is counter-intuitive to me that $2$ and $4$ are each less common than $1$ and $3$ and $5$, as I cannot see an intuitive parity issue

Comment: @Henry  I seriously tried to sort out a reason for that, but failed.  In the end, it's a weird sort of race that's hard to sort out.  Just try to guess what the pattern would be for some parallel problem with a $20$ sided die.

Comment: I would have guessed "something similar" but could not express what that means.   So I did the calculations with more sides (including with different cuttoffs), and it got stranger: (a) the probability of $0$ increases with the cuttoff in an intuitively natural way;   (b) there is a counter-intuitive $\omega$ type shape with two low areas (corresponding to the $2$ and $4$ with $6$-sided dice) though with very low cuttoffs not all of the left part of this appears; and (c) with cuttoffs more than $1$ more than the number of sides, some low positive values are equally probable.